# load the angular component on click using mat tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular & material for my tab, Below is my tab code.

Right now it is loading all the three tabs on single shot. But I need to load this component on click only.
I saw the we have option to capture the click event. But I don't know to load the component on click of the tab.Please help me to load the component on clik

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Region"> 
    <app-region><app-region>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Country"> 
    <app-country><app-country>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="State"> 
  <app-state><app-state>
  
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<ng-template matTabContent>`:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Region">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-region><app-region>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Country">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-country><app-country>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="State">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-state><app-state>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading):

> Tab contents can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a `ng-template` with the `matTabContent` attribute.

```
<mat-tab label="First">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
    Content 1 - Loaded: {{getTimeLoaded(1) | date:'medium'}}
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```